# can we start multiple clients. tornado client-side?

Tags: websocket, client, tornado

```
class DetectClient(object):
def __init__(self, url):
    self.url = url
    self.ws = None
    self.connect()
    PeriodicCallback(self.heartbeat, 3000).start()
    IOLoop.instance().start()

@gen.coroutine
def connect(self):
    try:
        self.ws = yield websocket_connect(self.url)
    except Exception as e:
        print("connection error, %s" % e)
    else:
        print("detect connected.")
        self.run()
```

it seems only one client instance can be started by some reason.
like this, how to start two instances of this client in the main function?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    DetectClient('ws.//1231231')
    DetectClient('ws.//1231231')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't start IOLoop in every client. You only have to start the IOLoop once globally.

For running multiple coroutines simultaneously, you can use [`gen.multi`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.multi):

Here's a modified code example (I've not tested it):

```py
from tornado import gen, ioloop

class DetectClient(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.ws = None

    @gen.coroutine
    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.ws = yield websocket_connect(self.url)
        except Exception as e:
            print("connection error, %s" % e)
        else:
            print("detect connected.")
            self.run()

        PeriodicCallback(self.heartbeat, 3000).start()


@gen.coroutine
def main():
    waiter = gen.WaitIterator(
        DetectClient('ws.//1231231').connect(),
        DetectClient('ws.//1231231').connect()
    )

    while not waiter.done():
        try:
            yield waiter.next()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    loop.run_sync(main)
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer, it seems that loop.run_sync(main) will have a "tornado.gen.BadYieldError: yielded unknown object <generator object main at 0x7fb688497b50>" error, is there any way to solve that? sorry to bother you, really new to tornado and coroutine

Comment: @ZhipingLi Ah, sorry about that. You also have to decorate `main` function with `@gen.coroutine`. I've updated the answer. By the way, if you're using a newer Tornado version, you should just use `async def` coroutines instead of `@gen.coroutine`.